# `apt-get upgrade` stalls with zombie `dpkg` - what to do?

Tags: server, apt, dpkg, byobu, zombie

During an `apt-get upgrade` on a server, output stalled and in investigation I found a zombie `dpkg` process, but the `apt-get` process still alive. What is the best way to handle this? The dpkg log shows the last operation apparently completed successfully ("status installed ...).

A potential cause is that the `ssh` session in which I did `apt-get upgrade` is from a (local) terminal running in `byobu` and at the same time there is a lot of network traffic from my local machine to the server.

edit: Perhaps a more likely cause is a sluggish virtual hard disk (the server is a cloud instance)..

Comment: I tried sending a HUP to the apt-get process - seems to have helped (it continues setting up packages), but has stalled again. Will try another HUP in a minute...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend stoping dpkg. It can leave your system in an undetermined state where things are half-configured.

Comment: well, it's a zombie, so it's finished doing what it was doing, as the log seems to confirm. My hope was that sending HUP to the `apt-get` process would make it realise `dpkg` had finished.. and be relatively safe (as `dpkg` actually does the work). It does look like the server has IO issues though )_: Perhaps patience is what I need??

Comment: Yeah, is most likely some IO operation may slow things down (can be the HDD failing too). You may want to check the stats more closely.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same stalling behaviour of `apt-get` (used `synaptic`) and saw the zombie `dpkg` process. I had the "detail" window open and saw some other bug notices related to the same problem which indicate that the open "detail" window is the cause. I killed the `apt-list` (or similar) process, closed the "detail" window in synaptic and the upgrade ran to completion.

Comment: good info, but in my case, I don't think you can kill a zombie process, it being already dead ;)